# Insert into goes with empty value and attribute magento1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, php, database

I try to insert the static value I have here

```
public static function saveBrandsAction()
{
    $api = new Ns_Thorleif_Adminhtml_IndexController();
    $arr = array();
    $arr[] = array('brandId' => '123', 'name' => 'test', 'globalIdentifier' => '1020002020');

    $model = Mage::getModel('thorleif/brand')->addData($arr);
    var_dump($model);
    try {
        $insertId = $model->save()->getId();
        echo "Data successfully inserted. Insert ID: ".$insertId;
    } catch (Exception $e){
        echo $e->getMessage(); 
    }
}
```

but in the debug the query is like this

```
INSERT INTO `linio_brands` () VALUES ()
```

and my var dump looks like

> object(Ns_Thorleif_Model_Brand)#314 (15) { ["_eventPrefix":protected]=> string(13) "core_abstract" ["_eventObject":protected]=> string(6) "object" ["_resourceName":protected]=> string(14) "thorleif/brand" ["_resource":protected]=> NULL ["_resourceCollectionName":protected]=> string(25) "thorleif/brand_collection" ["_cacheTag":protected]=> bool(false) ["_dataSaveAllowed":protected]=> bool(true) ["_isObjectNew":protected]=> NULL ["_data":protected]=> array(1) { [0]=> array(3) { ["brandId"]=> string(3) "123" ["name"]=> string(4) "test" ["globalIdentifier"]=> string(10) "1020002020" } } ["_hasDataChanges":protected]=> bool(true) ["_origData":protected]=> NULL ["_idFieldName":protected]=> NULL ["_isDeleted":protected]=> bool(false) ["_oldFieldsMap":protected]=> array(0) { } ["_syncFieldsMap":protected]=> array(0) { } }
>      Data successfully inserted. Insert ID: 5

something is wrong?

Comment: try changing `$arr[]` to `$arr`

Comment: Yes it works but only to insert one row. I have many rows and for that I use the foreach and the $arr table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to put it like this the Foreach with the **setData** and **save** into the foreach

```
foreach ($xml->Body->Brands->Brand as $row) {
            $arr = array('brandId' => $row->BrandId, 'name' => $row->Name);
            $model = Mage::getModel('thorleif/brand')->setData($arr);
            $model->save();
        }
```

Comment: You can also accept you own answer ;)